# sort data by Date in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying list of data sorted by date from JSON using ReactJS.
My code only sorts the data by date and month only, but it does not take the year.

> It works fine for other fields such as {contact.agencyEmail, contact.messageT, contact.message}
>
> How do I make this code to sort by date.

This is my component notifications.jsx

````
export class CompanyNotifications extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { contacts: [],    sort: {
            direction: 'desc',
          } };

      compareBy(key) {
        return function (a, b) {
          if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
          if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
          return 0;
        };
      }

Sorting for Assending and descending order

```   sortBy(key) {
        const direction = this.state.sort ? (this.state.sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc') : 'desc';

        let arrayCopy = [...this.state.contacts];
        arrayCopy.sort(this.compareBy(key));
        this.setState({contacts: arrayCopy});

        if (direction === 'asc') {
            arrayCopy.reverse();
          }

          this.setState({
            data: arrayCopy,
            sort: {
              direction,
            }
          });
      }

Fetched the data when component mount, by default data is in ascending order

      componentDidMount() {
        fetch('../companyNotifications.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            data.sort((a,b) => a.dateCreated.localeCompare(b.dateCreated));
this.setState({ contacts: data })
.then(data => this.setState({ contacts: data }));


        })
        .catch(console.log)
      }

 render() {

    const Contacts = ({ contacts }) => {
        return (
        <div class="table-container">


            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table100-head">
                        <th class="column1" onClick={() => this.sortBy('dateCreated')}>Date Created<FontAwesomeIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={faSort}/></th>
                        <th class="column2" onClick={() => this.sortBy('agencyEmail')}>Agency Email<FontAwesomeIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={faSort}/></th>
                        <th class="column3" onClick={() => this.sortBy('messageT')}>Message Type<FontAwesomeIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={faSort}/></th>
                        <th class="column4">Message</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {contacts.map((contact) => (

                    <tr>
                        <td class="column1">{contact.dateCreated}</td>
                        <td class="column2">{contact.agencyEmail}</td>
                        <td class="column3">{contact.messageT}</td>
                        <td class="column4">{contact.message}</td>
                    </tr>
                    ))}

                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
        )
      };

  }
}


This is the result i'm getting from my code

>01/12/2019

>01/13/2018 

>02/22/2019

>06/30/2019 

>07/17/2019

>10/02/2019 

>11/01/2019


but I'm expecting

>01/12/2019 

>02/22/2019

>06/30/2019 

>07/17/2019

>10/02/2019 

>11/01/2019

>01/13/2018
````

Comment: its not readable, format this code, add it to jsFiddle or sandbox

Comment: My go-to for anything date related in Moment.js. Use moment on each of your dates and then use the comparison operators it gives you. a.isBefore(b), a.isAfter(b), a.isSameOrBefore(b), a.isSameOrAfter(b). Google Moment.js and check out the docs.

Comment: @Brant Moment.js has quite a big bundle size and pulling it in just for comparing dates is quite an overkill. This can be done with built-in functions. If it really needs to be done with a library I'd pick [`date-fns`](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns) instead which is much smaller and allows for tree shaking.

Comment: That's correct. Seeing as I tend to work on larger apps that already have some reliance on Moment, it's already there to use. I take that for granted sometimes. :)

Comment: Thank you. I used mement js just for date field. And it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's doing a string comparison - so it's not sorting it as dates. Try changing your sort for date to:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('../companyNotifications.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            data.sort((a,b) => new Date(a) < new Date(b) ? 1 : -1);
            this.setState({ contacts: data })
                .then(data => this.setState({ contacts: data }));
        })
        .catch(console.log)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are actually not sorting dates but strings. As your strings start with the month and `"0"` comes before `"1"` this will work.

But as years are more significant for sorting dates your approach doesn't work if the year comes last in your string representation of it.

Your either need to change the representation to have the year come first, then the month and then the day. Or you need to first transform them to real [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects before comparing them.